# Unity IAP not working in Apple Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, testflight

Having issues for the past days trying to make the IAP work on TestFlight for my 1st game app. 
IAP works fine in Unity Editor (fake store) and also on Google Play (internal test track).

I don't receive any product prices from the apple store and the buy buttons have no effect (no callbacks on *ProcessPurchase* or *OnPurchaseFailed* since I show popup windows for both scenarios).

Below is the status of my app and IAP :

[image: Application Status]

[image: IAP Status]

From other similar threads everything should be ok and working as TestFlight doesn't require the IAPs to be submitted nor it requires for sandbox users to be manually created.

Any hints on what to further test or how could I check logs/warnings/errors are much appreciated, thanks.

**Tools used** : Unity 2019.3.0 (IAP 2.0.6) and XCode 11.3.1

**Update 1**: OnInitializeFailed() is called with NoProductsAvailable err

Answer (score 18):

The reason why the initialization failed with **NoProductsAvailable** was because I didn't have an active agreement for paid apps, although it is testflight and there are no real money involved, you still need to have this setup.

Here is how it should look like :

[image]
Once this was solved the IAPs worked fine.

Comment: This was needed when the app itself was free too.

Comment: Here's a link to it https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving "Received 0 products" until I filled in Contact Info, Bank Info and Tax Info.  After Add Tax  and active Everthing works fine