# IAP are not displayed in TestFlight but are displayed in XCode

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, testflight, in-app-subscription

There's a problem. Locally in xcode subscriptions are displayed. But if I load the application in testflight - I don't get the list of subscriptions.

**What I have at the moment:**

- The app has not been released yet.
- Subscriptions have ready to ship.
- The rights to create subscriptions are not with me, but with my boss.
- I created an account in sandBox and it shows up on my physical device.
- Locally I have been working with the configuration.storekit file. It synced and pulled up the subscriptions I needed.

If you need more information - write a comment and I'll add all the necessary information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to the problems.
In general, check it out. If you are just about to release an app and there are no subscriptions in Testflight - be sure to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60227781/16517701).
My boss didn't have the **Paid Apps** field filled in. **Be sure to look to make sure it is active.**

Comment: Submitting the "Paid Apps" agreement fixed the issue for me. Link: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/